# Data from two different JSONs into same struct in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, twitter

I have a struct which takes two parameters:

```
class feedStruct: NSObject {
    var type: String?
    var date: String?

  //Irrelevant
}
```

I then have two different types of JSONs, one taking data from my webpage and the other taking data from Twitter. They each display this data in their own custom cell in my `UITableViewController`.

The meaning of it is to have the above parameters from both JSONs, so the webpage JSON is getting the date from the webpage and putting in `"web"` as the type of the `feedStruct`.

The Twitter JSON is doing the same but with the type of "twitter" in `feedStruct`.

**Relevant code from HomeModel.swift (gets JSON from my webpage)**

```
var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
let locations = NSMutableArray()
let feeds = NSMutableArray()

for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
{
    jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

    let location = LocationModel()
    let feed = feedStruct()

    //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
    if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
        let title = jsonElement["title"] as? String,
        let article = jsonElement["article"] as? String,
        let id = jsonElement["id"] as? String,
        let category = jsonElement["category"] as? String,
        let unixstamp = jsonElement["unixstamp"] as? String
    {
        location.name = name
        location.title = title
        location.article = article
        location.id = id
        location.category = category
        location.unixstamp = unixstamp

        feed.date = unixstamp
        feed.type = "web"
    }

    locations.add(location)
    feeds.add(feed)
}

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
    self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: locations)
    self.delegate.feedDatesDownloaded(items: feeds)
})
```

**Relevant code from twitterModel.swift (gets JSON from twitter)**

```
var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
let feeds = NSMutableArray()

for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
{
    jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

    let feed = feedStruct()

    //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
    if let unixstamp = jsonElement["created_at"] as? String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: unixstamp)!
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date)
        let finalDate = calendar.date(from:components)

        let timestamp = finalDate?.timeIntervalSince1970
        let finalTimestamp = String(format: "%.0f", timestamp!)

        feed.date = finalTimestamp
        feed.type = "twitter"
    }

    feeds.add(feed)
}

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
    self.delegate.twitterDownloaded(items: jsonResult)
    self.delegate.feedDatesDownloaded(items: feeds)
})
```

In the `feedTableViewController` I have this function receiving the data for the `feedStruct`:

```
func feedDatesDownloaded(items: NSArray) {
    feedDates = items
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is, that the data from the web is stored first. When the twitter data is storing too, the web data is deleted.

**Is there some way I can stored them both, in the same feedStruct, and get a `feedDates.count` of 54 (web data: 34, twitter data: 20)?**

**EDIT**
Changed it to Array instead of NSMutable and replaces .add with .append.
Now it gives me two Dictionaries with a dictionary inside and a lot of them! Cannot even put all the code here, so this is just a example:

```js
[[Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]]
[[Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515970800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515193200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514847600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514674800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514329200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513983600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513551600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513206000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512946800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512601200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512169200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511910000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511650800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511305200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1510441200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509836400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509577200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509228000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508709600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508018400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506895200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506463200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506204000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505772000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505599200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505340000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1504994400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503784800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503525600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503180000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502834400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502575200")], [Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516719600"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]]
[[Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515970800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515193200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514847600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514674800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514329200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513983600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513551600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513206000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512946800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512601200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512169200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511910000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511650800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511305200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1510441200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509836400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509577200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509228000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508709600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508018400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506895200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506463200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506204000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505772000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505599200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505340000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1504994400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503784800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503525600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503180000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502834400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502575200")], [Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516719600"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]]
[[Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515970800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515193200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514847600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514674800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514329200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513983600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513551600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513206000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512946800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512601200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512169200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511910000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511650800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511305200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1510441200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509836400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509577200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509228000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508709600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508018400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506895200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506463200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506204000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505772000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505599200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505340000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1504994400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503784800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503525600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503180000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502834400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502575200")], [Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516719600"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]]
[[Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515970800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1515193200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514847600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514674800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1514329200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513983600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513551600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1513206000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512946800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512601200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1512169200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511910000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511650800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1511305200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1510441200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509836400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509577200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1509228000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508709600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508277600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1508018400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506895200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506463200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1506204000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505772000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505599200"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1505340000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1504994400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503784800"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503525600"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1503180000"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502834400"), Type: Optional("web"), Date: Optional("1502575200")], [Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516719600"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516716000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516712400"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516708800"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516626000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000"), Type: Optional("twitter"), Date: Optional("1516590000")]]
```

Comment: *Assigning* something to a variable like `feedDates = items` overwrites existing data. That the normal behavior. If you want to keep existing data you have to *append* or *insert* the new one. By the way, don't use `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift. You are throwing away the type information.

Comment: @vadian I thought of `append` too, but it will not let me do that. If I change the `NSMutable` to `NSArray` it won't let me use the `add()` function in `feeds.add(feed)`

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` either. Use Swift native types `Array` and `Dictionary`. `var` makes them mutable.

Comment: I have edited the question, after I used array.

Answer (score 0):

First. Don't use Objective-C collections, because you are throwing away the type information (see the previous comment) and it also can lead to some performance issues. What about your question, I don't understand it. If you want to load data both from web server and twitter before you update the table view, you can use DispatchGroup. If not, explain what exactly you would like to fix

Comment: I have edited the question, after using Array instead of NSMutable